# Drupal6 auto creation of node

Tags: drupal-6

I'm working with Drupal 6.
What i'd like to accomplish is to have a node created when a user registers. The node should be owned by the new registered user and have, for example, a title with username in it

scenario:

1) user "bunny" registers
2) a new node (of some kind) is created for that user
3) the new node title is "title_bunny"
4) the user is then redirected to the node editing

is this possible with actions or with some existing module?

thanks in advance
Maur

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible with a custom module. You'd want to use `hook_user` to tie into the registration process (via the 'insert' operation) and add your steps to it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [Content Profile Module](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile). IIRC, it does pretty much what you want.